# Validação de Hora

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask-plugin

Pessoal estou fazendo uma validação de hora em *Javascript*. Não consigo digitar as seguintes horas 14:00, 15:00, 16:00 até 20:00, mas outras horas consigo.

*Estou fazendo assim:*

```js
var mask = "HH:MM",
    pattern = {
        'translation': {
            'H': {
                pattern: /[0-23]/
            },
            'M': {
                pattern: /[0-59]/
            }
        }
    };
$("#QuantidadeHoras").mask(mask, pattern);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="QuantidadeHoras" />
```

Comment: Qual a(s) biblioteca(s) que você está utilizando para máscara e validação?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar isso `0-23` a regex nao entende como sendo de 0 até 23, mas sim de 0 ate 2, isso por que regex 0 2 faz parte do "range" que voce especificou na lista. A sua regex casaria com numeros de 0 a 2 seguidos do 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/[0-23]/` quer dizer `0`, `1`, `2`, ou `3`.

E o mesmo se aplica para o segundo caso, `[0-59]` significa de `0` a `5`, ou `9`.

---

Em vez disso, use este outro:

```js
var mask = function (val) {
    val = val.split(":");
    return (parseInt(val[0]) > 19)? "HZ:M0" : "H0:M0";
}

pattern = {
    onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        field.mask(mask.apply({}, arguments), options);
    },
    translation: {
        'H': { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false },
        'Z': { pattern: /[0-3]/, optional: false },
        'M': { pattern: /[0-5]/, optional: false}
    }
};

$('#QuantidadeHoras').mask(mask, pattern);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="QuantidadeHoras" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive que ajustar o pattern para funcionar a máscara, por algum motivo o plugin só reconhecia o primeiro número como parte integrante da máscara, segue como resolvi.

```js
var mask = "JG:MM",
    pattern = {
        'translation': {
            'J': {
                pattern: /[0-2]/
            },
            'G': {
                pattern: /[0-9]/
            },
            'M': {
                pattern: /[0-59]/
            }
        }
    };

$("#QuantidadeHoras").mask(mask, pattern);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="QuantidadeHoras" />
```

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e consegui colocar `25:00`.

Comment: Como o @Marconi observou, alem da hora que vai aceitar 24,25,26,27,28 e 29, os minutos nao vao funcionar bem, pelo mesmo motivo do comentario que fiz na pergunta, por mais que pareça o numero 17 nao esta no seu intervalo, que vai de 0 ate 5 ou 9.

Comment: Sugiro para você usar um plugin de timepicker, ou usar o próprio campo time do HTML5

Comment: Eu realmente me enganei, vocês tem razão, removo a resposta? É pra ser feito com regex, vou fazer us, já volto... rs

Comment: @Ruggi você pode editar concertando a resposta. :)